# How style endIcon of styled-component button?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Here is my simple styled button

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos';

const MyButton = styled(Button)`
  font-size: 11px;
`;

<MyButton
     variant="outlined"
     color="primary"
     size="small"
     disableElevation
     endIcon={<ArrowForwardIosIcon />}
>
     CLICK ME
</MyButton>
```

So how do I change endIcon size. I can change it in Chrome dev tool but have no idea what to add to MyButton definition. Assume it should be something like this in styled button definition:

```
  &.MuiButtonendIcon {
    color: green;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can style the individual endIcon by targeting the `svg` element and setting its `font-size` property like this

```
 const MyButton = styled(Button)`
  & .MuiButton-endIcon svg {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: green;
  }
`;
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work

Comment: ideally, it should work, please refer this https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-edison-2py6u?file=/src/App.js  which has the same code

Comment: yes.. that works in your example.. Seems button class is not getting resolved in my code: .MuiButtonendIcon-0-56-59

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
 const MyButton = styled(Button)`
  *:first-of-type svg{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: green;
  }
`;
```